# How to calculate an effect size on logistic regression on R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm running logistic regression in R and all the variables are significant, so I would like to find out the effect size of each variable.
How I'm doing this on R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is via caret package:

```
data(anorexia, package = "MASS")
reg <- glm(Postwt ~ Prewt + Treat + offset(Prewt),
            family = gaussian, data = anorexia)

library(caret)
varImp(reg)
```

Comment: I'm new with R, so I didn't realize from your answer how I use this package on my dataset ?

Comment: The first line is just for downloading example data set, so you can skip that line and second line is for regression so I assume you have already done that too. First you need to install 'caret' package then load package via library(caret) and use the function 'varImp' on your variable in which regression is stored as shown above varImp(reg)

Comment: I have another question: I've got this results:                                            Overall
X1    65809678
X2    50111785
X3   16093650
X4   49977413
X5   71412874
X6   36319605
X7   32610347
X8   9910535                                                                                                        How do I set those numbers into scale from 1 to 100 in order to rate their importance?

Comment: Depending on the model varImp  calculates Importance differently as I came to know that for linear model it simply takes the absolute t-value as a measure of importance [link](https://topepo.github.io/caret/variable-importance.html) . I encourage you to explore more about t-value and its corresponding P-value. To conclude I don't know if it make sense to put it into a scale 1-100 in this method.  Lastly if you find any of my answer or comment helpful, I would appreciate if you would accept my answer or vote-up.